# How to create a Laravel 5.4 Session in the Database

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I've scoured the documentation and I've spent hours trying to figure this out, and this is really my last resort. If this doesn't work I may have to get a subscription to Laracasts. I'm following this guide and it doesn't seem to be working for me. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

I'm hoping that someone can help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong. When I do my API request I get a success response and it returns the user from the database, but it doesn't create the session in the session table. Also, I don't get any errors in laravel.log.

I can create a user with no problems. I can match hashed passwords when retrieving the user.

api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/users', 'UserApiController@login');
```

UserApiController.php

```
public function login()
{
    $input = Request::all();
    $user = new User();
    $response = ['success' => false];
    if (!$user->validate($input))
    {
        return response()->json($response, 412);
    }
    $user = User::where('Email', $input['Email'])->where('Password', User::makePassword($input['Password']))->first();

    Log::info($user); //returns the user object successfully

    if (!isset($user))
    {
        return response()->json($response, 401);
    }
    session('user', $input]);  //<--this is not working
    $response['success'] = true;
    return response()->json($response, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you wrote what you really want to achieve, but this is what I think - you are using `api` middleware group and you want to use sessions. But if you look at `app/Http/Kernel.php` you will see sessions are used by default only by `web` middleware group:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

so you can either add this middleware to `api` group or rethink what you really want to achieve because APIs are usually stateless so you normally don't use sessions for them because in each request you send authorization data (`api_token` in this case by default) so each time you can find out which user is making the request

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing a fresh re-install and setting up Socialite and this time I used the default setting for authentication.